# How to recursively get diagonals given the row and column of an element in a 2D list of any dimensions?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

I want to write a recursive function that gets the diagonals to a cell element given the cell's row and column indexes. My algorithm so far only progresses to get the diagonal going to the bottom right of the 2D list, but I'd like it to get all the diagonals for any cell position. `rs cs` are the row and column indexes of the cell we want to get the diagonals for and `r c` are the current cell's indexes.

I have the general idea, but I can't get the specifics down. It's been a while since I've delved into recursion and I could use some help.

```
#self is an instance of Board
def getDiag(self,rs,cs,r,s,lst=[],recCount=0):
 if recCount == 0:
    #boardList holds lists of BoardCell instances. Its attributes are irrelevant.
    lst.append[self.boardList[rs][cs]]
 else:
  lst.append[self.boardList[r][c]]

 if rs + 1 < len(self.boardlist) and cs + 1 < len(self.boardlist[0]):
    return self.getDiag(rs,cs,rs+1,rs+1,lst,recCount+1)
```

Comment: Why do you need two points [r,c] and [rs,cs] ? You want to get diagonals for just one [rs, cs] isn't it? What is the relation between these two points?

Comment: I was thinking that ```[r,c]``` could be used to check if the cell at that point is in the diagonal of ```[rs,cs]```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing to remember with recursion is we need to decide

1. When to stop
2. How the next recursion is going to be related to the current one.

Now let's break the problem down.

- When you want diagonals from a given square, you want *that square*, plus the diagonals going top-right, top-left, bottom-right, and bottom-left from that square.
- When you fall off the edge (`rs < 0`, `rs > row count`, `cs < 0`, `cs > col count`), we need to stop the recursion.
- For every other square, return itself, plus the diagonal in the appropriate direction

Here's some code that'll return the indices of the diagonal cells. Returning the values of the diagonal cells is a fairly trivial change from this:

```
class Board:
    
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        self.boardRows = r
        self.boardCols = c

    def getDiag(self, rs, cs, direction='all'):
        
        if not 0 <= rs < self.boardRows or not 0 <= cs < self.boardCols:
            # fall off the edge
            return []
        
        if direction == 'all':
            return [[rs, cs]] + self.getDiag(rs - 1, cs + 1, 'topright') + self.getDiag(rs - 1, cs - 1, 'topleft') + self.getDiag(rs + 1, cs + 1, 'bottomright') + self.getDiag(rs + 1, cs - 1, 'bottomleft')
        
        # Just something to handle 'direction'
        if 'top' in direction: 
            delta_r = -1
        else:
            delta_r = 1
    
        if 'left' in direction: 
            delta_c = -1
        else:
            delta_c = 1
        
        # This square, plus the remaining diagonal in the correct direction.
        return [[rs, cs]] + self.getDiag(rs + delta_r, cs + delta_c, direction=direction)

    def printDiag(self, rs, cs, direction='all'):
        board = [["o"] * self.boardCols for i in range(self.boardRows)]
        diagCells = self.getDiag(rs, cs, direction)
        for i, j in diagCells:
            board[i][j] = u"\u2022"
        
        board[rs][cs] = "*"
        
        print("-\t" + "\t".join(str(i) for i in range(self.boardCols)))
        print("\n".join([f"{rownum}\t" + "\t".join(row) for rownum, row in enumerate(board)]))
```

To test, let's print unmarked squares as `o`, marked squares as `•`, and the originating square as `*`:

```
b = Board(5, 5)

# Middle diagonal
print(b.getDiag(2, 2))
b.printDiag(2, 2)
Output: 
[[2, 2], [1, 3], [0, 4], [1, 1], [0, 0], [3, 3], [4, 4], [3, 1], [4, 0]]
-   0   1   2   3   4
0   •   o   o   o   •
1   o   •   o   •   o
2   o   o   *   o   o
3   o   •   o   •   o
4   •   o   o   o   •


# Top-left diagonal
print(b.getDiag(0, 0))
b.printDiag(0, 0)
Output: 
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
-   0   1   2   3   4
0   *   o   o   o   o
1   o   •   o   o   o
2   o   o   •   o   o
3   o   o   o   •   o
4   o   o   o   o   •

# Bottom-right diagonal
print(b.getDiag(4, 4))
b.printDiag(4, 4)
Output:
[[4, 4], [3, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1], [0, 0]]
-   0   1   2   3   4
0   •   o   o   o   o
1   o   •   o   o   o
2   o   o   •   o   o
3   o   o   o   •   o
4   o   o   o   o   *

# Top-right diagonal
print(b.getDiag(0, 4))
b.printDiag(0, 4)
Output:
[[0, 4], [1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4, 0]]
-   0   1   2   3   4
0   o   o   o   o   *
1   o   o   o   •   o
2   o   o   •   o   o
3   o   •   o   o   o
4   •   o   o   o   o

# Bottom-left diagonal
print(b.getDiag(4, 0))
b.printDiag(4, 0)
Output:
[[4, 0], [3, 1], [2, 2], [1, 3], [0, 4]]
-   0   1   2   3   4
0   o   o   o   o   •
1   o   o   o   •   o
2   o   o   •   o   o
3   o   •   o   o   o
4   *   o   o   o   o

# Top-edge diagonal
print(b.getDiag(0, 2))
b.printDiag(0, 2)
Output:
[[0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
-   0   1   2   3   4
0   o   o   *   o   o
1   o   •   o   •   o
2   •   o   o   o   •
3   o   o   o   o   o
4   o   o   o   o   o

# Right-edge diagonal
print(b.getDiag(2, 4))
b.printDiag(2, 4)
Output:
[[2, 4], [1, 3], [0, 2], [3, 3], [4, 2]]
-   0   1   2   3   4
0   o   o   •   o   o
1   o   o   o   •   o
2   o   o   o   o   *
3   o   o   o   •   o
4   o   o   •   o   o

# Bottom-edge diagonal
print(b.getDiag(4, 2))
b.printDiag(4, 2)
Output:
[[4, 2], [3, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [2, 0]]
-   0   1   2   3   4
0   o   o   o   o   o
1   o   o   o   o   o
2   •   o   o   o   •
3   o   •   o   •   o
4   o   o   *   o   o

# Left-edge diagonal
print(b.getDiag(2, 0))
b.printDiag(2, 0)
Output:
[[2, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2], [3, 1], [4, 2]]
-   0   1   2   3   4
0   o   o   •   o   o
1   o   •   o   o   o
2   *   o   o   o   o
3   o   •   o   o   o
4   o   o   •   o   o
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much!